# Weird error when importing matplotlib with eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib

When trying to import `matplotlib.pyplot` in the python console on eclipse, it gives me this error:

> object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

But if I import `matplotlib.pyplot` in the console python itself offers, it can be imported successfully.

Comment: Are you sure that the python interpreter associated with the eclipse project is the same as the one you are manually trying the import?

Comment: I think so.I installed PyDev on eclipse and then callout the console by Window->Show Veiw->Console->PyDev Console , I can import other modules successfully on this console.

Comment: See under `Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter Python` which one is set as the default interpreter for your project.

Comment: It's E:/Python2.7/python.exe.Is this correct?I double clicked it and try to import matplotlib on it,it works.

Comment: Then I cant help :( Everything should work correctly. Try updating to newer PyDev, if you already haven't. Btw is that the complete stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure this error is related to importing matplotlib and not an error in the rest of the script?

Comment: I solved it though I am not quite sure how I did it.I uninstalled python and downloaded a new eclipse package.Then I set the configurations of PyDev in eclipse again.But this time I set the configurations after installing matplotlib module.And then it works.So maybe the problem is that I have to reset the Python interpreter configurations of pydev after installing a new module.Thank both of you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried importing matplotlib.pylab, as it is alias for pyplot? And if you still get the error from eclipse syntax check, just try to run it.